# how to await Office.context.ui.addHandlerAsync ()?

Tags: typescript, office365, ms-office, office-addins, excel-addins

i want to **await the Office.context.ui.addHandlerAsync()** funtion in excel office js, there is any other solution for it...

in the initial time, it's able to await but after refresh it's not able to await...so what there is an issue...

i tryed too many things but not getting any idea

there is any other solution in office api?

Is this a problem with API version ?

[i am not getting any await effect]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvVQ3.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TX6Js.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.